# sharepoint listfielditerator fails to load in Application page

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to pragmatically add  listfielditerator control inside a panel. Below is my sample code.

```
ListFieldIterator spCtrls = new ListFieldIterator();
        spCtrls.ID = "lstfields";
        spCtrls.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Edit;
        spCtrls.ListId = listId;
        spCtrls.ItemId = itemid;
        spCtrls.TemplateName = "ListFieldIterator";
        pnlSPCtrl.Controls.Add(spCtrls);

        SaveButton btnSave = new SaveButton();
        btnSave.ID = "bs";
        btnSave.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Edit;
        btnSave.ListId = listId;
        btnSave.ItemId = itemid;
        pnlFooter.Controls.Add(btnSave);

        DeleteItemButton btnDelete = new DeleteItemButton();
        btnDelete.ID = "bd";
        btnDelete.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Edit;
        btnDelete.ListId = listId;
        btnDelete.ItemId = itemid;
        pnlFooter.Controls.Add(btnDelete);
```

All the controls in the list are rendering. However, when i try to search and add a user in  the peoplepicker control, i get a error:

```
The target &#39;ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$lstfields$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$UserField&#39; for the callback could not be found or did not implement ICallbackEventHandler.
```

Also, I have the taxonomy field which gets hanged when i try to select the tags.

Any idea where i went wrong?

Thanks,
Mallikarjun

Comment: You should try on http://sharepoint.Stackexchange.com

Comment: @SteveB One thing i really do not understand why this `Sharepoint` tag is provided in this forum if SO do not entertain Sharepoint questions and suggests to move question to sharepoint.stackexchange.com?